# problem in visualized image derived from npz file

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation, npz-file

I am trying to open and visualize images of different ct slices in a npz formatted file to proceed my NN segmentation task later on.
I used the following code:

```
data = np.load('case0005_slice060.npz')
image = data['image']
img = Image.fromarray(image,'RGB')
```

and finally, I could visualize the image, but it seems there is a problem somewhere that I can't understand. here is the output (the problem is that I may need to solve overlapped images but I don't know how)

[image]

Comment: also obviously my images are not RGB, so how can i drop RGB and treat them as BW images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check what you have. You need to know the shape and type of your Numpy array:

```
print(image.shape, image.dtype)
```

If the shape is of the form `h,w,3` it's likely RGB. If of the form `h,w`, it's likely greyscale and you could put `'L'` as the mode when creating your `PIL Image` from it instead of `'RGB'`, though you can normally leave the mode out and it is inferred from the Numpy array shape.

You then need to consider the `dtype`. If `np.uint8`, you're all set. If other than that, you may need to provide one of the [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) PIL accepts, or cast with something like:

```
img = Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks.
I normalized the image which was float32 and removed the RGB here is the final code:

```
from numpy import load
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def normalize8(I):
    mn = I.min()
    mx = I.max()

    mx -= mn

    I = ((I - mn)/mx) * 255
    return I.astype(np.uint8)

data = np.load('case0005_slice060.npz')
print(data.files)
image = data['image']
image=normalize8( image)
img = Image.fromarray(image)
```

[image]